# addition of 2 pytorch tensors with diffrent size

Tags: pytorch, addition, tensor

I have 2 tensors with dimension, A = [64,155,300] and B =[64,155,100]
when I add this 2 tensors ie. C= A+B, 
I get this error ==> " RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (300) must match the size of tensor b (100) at non-singleton dimension 2 "

could anyone please help how should I add above tensors? any help will be appreciated!

Comment: what shape do you hope C will be?

Comment: How exactly do you want to add them? Sum them (how??) ? Or concatenate? Something yet different?

Answer (score 3):

As error says you can not add two tensor with mis-match shapes
but if you want you can repeat your third dim of B tensor so it can match with A
using [`torch.Tensor.repeat`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html?highlight=torch%20tensor%20repeat#torch.Tensor.repeat) try `A + B.repeat(1,1,3)`

```py
>>> A.shape
torch.Size([64, 155, 300])

>>> B.shape
torch.Size([64, 155, 100])

>>> B = B.repeat(1,1,3)

>>> B.shape
torch.Size([64, 155, 300])

>>> C = A + B

>>> C.shape
torch.Size([64, 155, 300])
```